# ORA-56901: non-constant expression is not allowed for pivot|unpivot values (DATE)

Tags: oracle, plsql, pivot

I'm getting an error saying that non-constant expressions cannot be used within PIVOT (ORA-56901) in the code provided below. I need to put dynamic dates inside PIVOT. Can you help?

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TABLO_SP
AS
Q1_TARIH_ILK DATE;
Q2_TARIH_ILK DATE;
Q3_TARIH_ILK DATE;
Q4_TARIH_ILK DATE;
Q1_TARIH_SON DATE;
Q2_TARIH_SON DATE;
Q3_TARIH_SON DATE;
Q4_TARIH_SON DATE;
TARIH_GUNCEL DATE;
BEGIN 
Q4_TARIH_ILK:=TO_DATE('01.01.'||to_char(extract(year from sysdate)-1));
Q1_TARIH_ILK:=TO_DATE('31.03.'||to_char(extract(year from sysdate)-1));
Q2_TARIH_ILK:=TO_DATE('30.06.'||to_char(extract(year from sysdate)-1));
Q3_TARIH_ILK:=TO_DATE('30.09.'||to_char(extract(year from sysdate)-1));
Q1_TARIH_SON:=TO_DATE('01.01.'||to_char(extract(year from sysdate)));
Q2_TARIH_SON:=TO_DATE('31.03.'||to_char(extract(year from sysdate)));
Q3_TARIH_SON:=TO_DATE('30.06.'||to_char(extract(year from sysdate)));
Q4_TARIH_SON:=TO_DATE('30.09.'||to_char(extract(year from sysdate)));
SELECT DEGER_1 INTO TARIH_GUNCEL FROM TABLO_2 WHERE TARIH = TRUNC(SYSDATE);

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE TABLO';

INSERT INTO  TABLO  
with 
ANAVERI AS (
SELECT DEGER_1,
TARIH,
DEGER_2,
DEGER_3
FROM
        TABLO_3
    WHERE 
        TARIH IN (
        Q1_TARIH_ILK, Q2_TARIH_ILK, Q3_TARIH_ILK, Q4_TARIH_ILK, Q1_TARIH_SON, Q2_TARIH_SON, 
Q3_TARIH_SON, Q4_TARIH_SON, TARIH_GUNCEL
        )
        AND DEGERR_1=1
        ),
KURUMSAL AS
(
    SELECT 
        DEGER_1,
        TARIH,
        FACT_BAKIYETL
    FROM 
    ANAVERI
    WHERE 
        (
SUBSTR(DEGER_2,1,3) IN (SELECT DEGER_5 FROM TABLO_4 a JOIN TABLO_5 b ON a.SAT=b.SAT and b.SAT =90)
OR SUBSTR(DEGER_2,1,4) IN (SELECT DEGER_5 FROM TABLO_4 a JOIN TABLO_5 b ON a.SAT=b.SAT and b.SAT 
=90)
OR SUBSTR(DEGER_2,1,5) IN (SELECT DEGER_5 FROM TABLO_4 a JOIN TABLO_5 b ON a.SAT=b.SAT and b.SAT 
=90)
OR SUBSTR(DEGER_2,1,6) IN (SELECT DEGER_5 FROM TABLO_4 a JOIN TABLO_5 b ON a.SAT=b.SAT and b.SAT 
=90)
OR SUBSTR(DEGER_2,1,7) IN (SELECT DEGER_5 FROM TABLO_4 a JOIN TABLO_5 b ON a.SAT=b.SAT and b.SAT 
=90)
OR SUBSTR(DEGER_2,1,8) IN (SELECT DEGER_5 FROM TABLO_4 a JOIN TABLO_5 b ON a.SAT=b.SAT and b.SAT 
=90)
OR SUBSTR(DEGER_2,1,9) IN (SELECT DEGER_5 FROM TABLO_4 a JOIN TABLO_5 b ON a.SAT=b.SAT and b.SAT 
=90)
)
) 
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT
        ANAVERI.DEGER_1,
        KURUMSAL.TARIH,
        KURUMSAL.DEGER_3
FROM ANAVERI
        LEFT JOIN KURUMSAL
        ON KURUMSAL.DEGER_1=ANAVERI.DEGER_1)
        PIVOT(SUM(DEGER_3) 
        FOR TARIH IN (
        Q1_TARIH_ILK Q1_TARIH_ILK,
        Q1_TARIH_SON Q1_TARIH_SON,
        Q2_TARIH_ILK Q2_TARIH_ILK,
        Q2_TARIH_SON Q2_TARIH_SON,
        Q3_TARIH_ILK Q3_TARIH_ILK,
        Q3_TARIH_SON Q3_TARIH_SON,
        Q4_TARIH_ILK Q4_TARIH_ILK,
        Q4_TARIH_SON Q4_TARIH_SON,
        TARIH_GUNCEL TARIH_GUNCEL
        ))
            ;

            COMMIT;

            END;
```

Comment: Build the query as a string and insert the dynamic values into that string as literals and then use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to execute the query with only static values in the string. (Similar to how you truncate the table.)

Comment: You can convert the parts `extract(year from sysdate)` to `sysdate,'yyyy'` for the sake of brevity.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan If you were going to simplify that part then use `Q4_TARIH_ILK:=ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YY'), -12);` and `Q1_TARIH_ILK:=ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YY'), -8) - 1;`, etc. (rather than converting to years and then to a string and finally back to a date).